# Will graphql expose the schema structure to user ? or I should dealing access control by myself when work with gqlgen and ent

Tags: go, graphql, gqlgen

Since Golang ent library will automatically  generate the graphql schema base the struct  , but it will also generate the whole schema include something you don't want to expose to client, for example  like "hassedpassword" ,

```
type User implements Node {
  id: ID!
  userName: String!
  hassPassword: String!
  email: String!
}
```

```
type User struct {
    ID                int64             `json:"id"`
    UserName          string            `json:"userName"`
    HassPassword      string            `json:"hassPassword"`
    Email             string            `json:"email"`
}
```

due to it is automatically generated by library ent and gqlgen, you can't edit the schema , so I try to return a empty Hasspassword to client at resolver level ,it works well , but I found that  users can see the hashed password structure , when they interact with the playground , though it return nothing , is this ok ? is there a way to prevent  expose the hashed password  to the client ?

Is there a way to prevent expose the hashed password structure to the client ?  or you think this is totally fine ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with golang, but in general if you don't want to expose some data to client it shouldn't be in the schema at the first place.
So if you want to prevent from expose just remove `hassPassword` field from type `User`.

You mentioned that requesting `hassPassword`returns nothing. Do you mean it returns `null`?

If so there is something wrong going on, cause this field is `non-nullable`, which means it should throws an error in case of `null` value.